# Исключение MissingRuntimeArtifactException при использовании .NET Native

Tags: c#, uwp

У меня при компиляции сборки в `Release` появляется вот такая ошибка:

> Вызвано исключение: "" в
>   System.Private.Reflection.Execution.dll Вызвано исключение:
>   "System.Reflection.MissingRuntimeArtifactException" в
>   System.Private.Reflection.Execution.dll Cannot retrieve a MethodInfo
>   for this delegate because the method it targeted
>   (System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.ICommand_CCWAdapter.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(Object,
>   EventArgs)) was not enabled for metadata using the Dynamic attribute.
>   For more information, please visit
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=616868

По ссылке `https://dotnet.github.io/native/troubleshooter/method.html#` через конструктор попробовал указать метод динамическим, но проблема осталась.
Через конструктор вот что у меня получилось для файла `RD.XML`:

```
<Type Name="Alpha.ViewModels.MainViewModel">
  <MethodInstantiation Name="OnItemTappedAsync" Arguments="System.Object" Dynamic="Required" />
</Type>
```

Проблема вот здесь:

```
public ICommand ItemTappedCommand => new AsyncCommand((param) => OnItemTappedAsync(param));
```

В первый раз сталкиваюсь с данной проблемой, поэтому не знаю как правильно ее решить.